# Nodejs - How can I get values of config attribute in the net module?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to retrieve the values of these variables in the net library

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries 
net.core.somaxconn
net.core.netdev_max_backlog
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
```

I mean I am doing a debugging but I am not able to get them through the net object

Example

```
var net = require('net')
var server = net.createServer()
server.listen(1024,'localhost');

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("Hello World!!!")
console.log(net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog)
debugger
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Those two "net" values are totally different. The `net` module in node.js is merely something that allows you to create TCP clients and servers. If you need to change your OS configuration, you will need to either find a module that wraps that for you, or you will need to manually execute some child process that makes the necessary changes (e.g. `sysctl` on *nix).

Comment: Ok, but for example in the api I can read that the parameter "Backlog is the maximum length of the queue of pending connections. The actual length will be determined by your OS through sysctl settings such as tcp_max_syn_backlog and somaxconn on linux. The default value of this parameter is 511 (not 512)." so at least there should be a way to get tcp_max_syn_backlog and somaxconn. I mean I am supposing net module is already wrapping some of the most generic attributes in the config. Pls let me know your thougths and also if you already try any module to get config on sysctl. Many thanks

Comment: It doesn't provide a way to get those existing values, it's just allowing you to override the OS default backlog value when you start a TCP server.

Comment: Awesome, I understood before although now is much clear for me. Thanks +1